# How long does a string constant live in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, string-literals, object-lifetime

I've been wondering, how long does a string constant live in C++. For example, if I create some const char *str = "something" inside a function, would it be safe to return the value of str?

I wrote a sample program and was really surprised to see that such returned value still stored that string. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const char *func1()
{
    const char *c = "I am a string too";
    return c;
}

void func2(const char *c = "I'm a default string")
{
    cout << c << endl;
}

const int *func3()
{
    const int &b = 10;
    return &b;
}

int main()
{
    const char *c = "I'm a string";
    cout << c << endl;
    cout << func1() << endl;
    func2();
    func2("I'm not a default string");
    cout << *func3() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me the following output:

> I'm a string
>
> I am a string too
>
> I'm a default string
>
> I'm not a default string
>
> 10

The func3 is there just to find out if the same works with other types.
So the question is: is it safe to return a pointer to a string constant created within that function (as in func1())?
Also, is it safe to use the default string value as in func2()?

Comment: If it's in quotes, it lives forever.

Comment: `int j = 2;` -- how long does that 2 live? If you could do `int const *j = &2;`, the answer would still be the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A string literal has static storage duration and lasts the life of the program. From the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `2.14.5` *String literals* paragraph *8* which says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred
>   to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array
>   of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below,
>   and **has static storage duration (3.7).**

and from section `3.7.1` *Static storage duration* paragraph *1*:

> All variables which do not have dynamic storage duration, do not have
>   thread storage duration, and are not local have static storage
>   duration. **The storage for these entities shall last for the duration
>   of the program (3.6.2, 3.6.3).**

The second case in `func3` on the other other hand is not valid. The lifetime of a temporary bound to a reference persists for the life of the reference, which in this case ends when the function returns. This is covered in section `12.2` which says:

> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary.<sup>115</sup> The
>   temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the
>   complete object of a subobject to **which the reference is bound
>   persists for the lifetime of the reference except**:

Comment: Or forever, if it is stored in a ROM. I mean, a pointer can point anywhere, even into ROM.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And what about func3 here? Is its returned value expected to be valid after the function returned to main?

Comment: @SiLiKhon It, in general, will not work. You can see it if you change `int` to a class that has a destructor that yells something like "destructing" when it is going out of scope, and you'll see that the object will be destroyed before you call `cout` on it. In your example, the memory that that integer lives in hasn't been overwritten yet, so you are lucky that it prints the value you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

### Depends what type it is

If it is local automatic variable(pointer) it will be created on stack, and exists during function execution.
When function returns, this pointer stop existing.
But string literal itself will be in process memory as long as process itself.

I will just try to demonstrate what happens with local (automatic) string
initialized variable in *func1*.

1. We see that using relative addressing (current address + hardcoded offset)
   we calculate string literal address
2. This address is placed in register $rax
3. As **c** is local variable it should be defined on stack, and we see it is put on stack using stack address in $rbp

   ```
      0x00005555555551f1 <+8>:     lea    0xe0c(%rip),%rax        #0x555555556004
      0x00005555555551f8 <+15>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   ```
4. When *func1* returns, local variable **c** will be destroyed with the stack frame of *func1*
5. Local variable **c** will be returned using register $rax

   ```
      0x00005555555551fc <+19>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   ```

And we see all this in this screenshot from GDB:

[image]

We see that before return to main function, value of local string pointer c is placed in register $rax, so this register is used for passing return values to caller function.

But where is string literal?
It is in .rodata section of ELF file, as name says it is data section without write permission:

```
Hex dump of section '.rodata':
0x00002000 01000200 4920616d 20612073 7472696e ....I am a strin
0x00002010 6720746f 6f004927 6d206120 73747269 g too.I'm a stri
0x00002020 6e670049 276d2061 20646566 61756c74 ng.I'm a default
0x00002030 20737472 696e6700 49276d20 6e6f7420  string.I'm not 
0x00002040 61206465 6661756c 74207374 72696e67 a default string
```